# How to sort a structure array

Tags: arrays, matlab, structure, cell-array

How do I sort the oo structure array alphabetical order by item name.

```
oo = struct('Item', {'Quill','Ink Pen', 'Pencil'}, 'Cost', {10, 2, 1})
```

I tried using the sort() function but it didn't work?
Thank you.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First index your field, in this case `oo.Items` which returns a comma separated list. For string data use `{}` to concatenate to a cell of strings, otherwise use `[]` to get an array:

```
%get the right order using second output of sort
[~,index]=sort({oo.Item})
%sort it
oo=oo(index)
```