# Sorting on Structs In Matlab

Tags: matlab, sorting, struct

In Matlab I have an array of `structs("sort_on_this", ...)`

How do I sort the array on the on `sort_on_this`?

Example of what I am trying to do,

```
list_to_sort = [struct('a', 4), struct('a', 0), struct('a', 3), struct('a', 1)]
sort(list_to_sort on 'a') = 
      [struct('a', 0), struct('a', 1), struct('a', 3), struct('a', 4)]
```

edit: question is not [duplicate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29055332/how-to-sort-a-structure-array), because the the other question has arrays within the struct that needed to be sorted whereas this is an array of structs that needs to be sorted.

Comment: Sort with respect to what? Contents? Name? Size?

Comment: @Adriaan I want to sort with respect to the variable sort_on_this which is a number

Comment: @rayryeng I tried using the solution that you marked this [question a duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/a/29055553/3024116) to, but it has lists inside the struct not a list of structs. So this question is different.

Comment: That wasn't clear in your original post. Now that you made an edit, it's certainly different. Please make an effort to give as much detail as possible in future questions you post.

Comment: @rayryeng my apology, I was merely in a hurry this morning next time I will simple not post the question until enough detail is provided. Could you  please unmark it as a duplicate?

Comment: @DisplayName101 already done.

Comment: There are no arrays in the struct, you are miss-understanding the struct constructor. `list_to_sort = [struct('a', 4), struct('a', 0), struct('a', 3), struct('a', 1)]` and `list_to_sort = struct('a', {4,0,3,1})` both produce the same.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As you've probably figured out, the normal `sort` doesn't work on structs. You can, however, build an array of the *values* that you then sort and use the new ordering to reorder the original struct array.

Starting with our struct array:

```
list_to_sort = [struct('a', 4), struct('a', 0), struct('a', 3), struct('a', 1)]
```

Get the struct field values into an array:

```
a_values = [list_to_sort.a]

a_values =
   4   0   3   1
```

Now, sort `a_values`, keeping the second return value from [sort](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/sort.html) which gives us the original indices of the sorted values.

```
[~,inds] = sort(a_values)
inds =    
   2   4   3   1
```

Finally, use these indices to reorder your struct:

```
sorted_list = list_to_sort(inds)

>> disp([sorted_list.a])
   0   1   3   4
```